# waste money into or on?

Tags: prepositions

I have a problem. At English classes there was a sentence:

> Mike is wasting most of his money on/into clothes.

Teacher said that the right variant is "into". I tried to find some examples with "to waste into", but I found nothing.

Is it possible to say like that? If yes, can you give me some examples using "into"?

How can I prove that "on" is right?

Comment: @medica No quibbles about the content of your comment. I'd just like to explore the post's final question. The other prepositions can be derived by a 'physical' (or metaphorically physical) interpretation. There's no question that "on" is right and feels right in this context. The question is how to explain *why* it is right. Tradition and intuition aside, is there a metaphorical sense in which spending money has the notion that the money 'sits atop' (or is otherwise 'on') the clothes?

Comment: What medica says is correct.  For money it's invest in, pour into, waste on, give to.  And, as Lawrence suggests, there are not many good "rules" that will tell you which to use when -- mostly you just learn what's idiomatic as you learn the language.

Comment: @Lawrence - Dispel that silly notion that _on_ somehow implies "sits atop." Sure, _on_ **can** mean "sits atop", but that's just one of [several](https://www.wordnik.com/words/on) possible meanings for that two-letter word. If I'm on the telephone, on the radio, on a roll, on a train, on a diet, on drugs, or on fire, I'm mostly like not "sitting atop" any of those things.

Comment: @J.R. Of course, hence the phrase in parentheses. The aspect of the OP's question I'd like to explore isn't that *particular* meaning of *on*. It's whether there is some physical analogue *at all* that can serve to explain to the OP's teacher why, in this context, *on* is appropriate and *into* isn't. To put it another way, I'd like to say something more helpful here to the OP than *that's how it's always been*.

Comment: @J.R. -- If you're "on the can", however ...

Comment: @Lawrence - Okay, gotcha. I see what you were getting at now. Good question.

Comment: @Lawrence - It's a laudable goal, but it may prove chimerical. Some languages are more idiomatic and irregular than others, and the mother tongue is likely even more so than those. Cheers!

Comment: @Rob_Ster Fair call :) . Sometimes, there's not much more we can say than *I knows what I knows 'cause I knows it*, but it's in the nature of scientists and researchers to ask why. If the exact answer isn't forthcoming, even a close approximation can be satisfying. (In case you're interested, my current candidate in this case is on='in contact with'. It's not a particularly close match, but the idea of 'related to', or 'associated with', seems promising as an avenue for further research. If you're not interested, kindly ignore this bracketed section.)

Comment: to waste money on clothes/women/cars - See OALD  waste, no. 1   http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/waste_1?q=waste

Comment: @rogermue If you put your comment into a short answer, you will give the OP exactly what he needs -- otherwise your comment may get lost in the noise.

Answer (score 2):

The normal construction is to waste money on clothes or cars or women as you can see in OALD, waste no. 1:

- to waste something on something:
- Why waste money on clothes you don't need?
- We got straight down to business without wasting time on small talk.

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/waste_1?q=waste

But I can imagine that in some variants of English "into" might be possible.

Answer (score -3):

Either 'on' or 'into' is grammatically okay. However, the situation is not the same.
Mike is wasting most of his money *on* clothes.
The speaker of this sentence emphasizes that Mike wastes money "on" clothes other than books or something else.

Mike is wasting most of his money *into* clothes.
The speaker emphasizes that he wastes money "on" clothes "repeatedly".

The basic meaning of 'on' describes being contacted or fixed with while that of 'into' says being going further in some direction.

Comment: I can think of no instance where I've heard "wastes money into" ("_puts_ money into", yes, but not "wastes money into"). The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wastes+money+on%2Cwastes+money+into%2Cwaste+money+on%2Cwaste+money+into%2C+puts+money+into&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) can't find any instances either. As a side note, you can "put money _on_" something, too – but that means something [different](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+money+on).

Comment: Sorry, there is enough wrong with this answer that I downvoted it.  The second paragraph of the answer is just plain wrong.

Comment: Is that a theory or yours? I can't imagine that you have a source to back up your theory.